How do I create a custom field in Looker Studio that returns page path level one for GA4 data?
I am attempting to create a custom field in Looker Studio, that returns the page path level one data, for my Google Analytics data. In UA, this dimension was provided by default, but this is not the case for GA4.
Using ChatGPT/Gemini, I recommended a few different formulas to achieve this, but everything I have tried returns "null".
Here's the formula I'm using currently:
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page path, "^([^/]+)(?:/)")

Here's the result I'm getting:

Should this formula work, or is it invalid?

I struggle with a feature to achieve a custom dimension for page path: Custom group data does not match the equally filtered data in Looker (also wrong compared to GA4)
It is - to my knowledge - possible to use "Add group" in the data source level of GA4 and then have it as dimension to be filtered on a page path level but as mentioned above, for our dashboard unfortunately it displays wrong data at the moment.
